# WPF WebBrowser NavigateToStream is blank, but NavigateToString works with the same stream

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF application that uses the `WebBrowser` component to render an SVG.

The SVG can get quite large so I am writing it into a `MemoryStream` and then rendering it like this:

```
private void RenderStream(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        svgContainer.NavigateToStream(stream);
    }
```

However, when I do this, I just get the contents of `about:blank` in the browser control.

If I change the method so it looks like this:

```
private void RenderStream(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        var str = new StreamReader(stream);
        var stringified = str.ReadToEnd();
        svgContainer.NavigateToString(stringified);
    }
```

This shows the content I am expecting to see. Running the same code in a simple application it seems to work normally, so I am guessing it is either to do with the size of the stream or the something encoded in the content. Why are these behaving differently?

Comment: about:blank will be shown only if the stream is null. Are you releasing the stream before calling somehow?  Perhaps by using a using statement? As it will Navigate asynchronously to the stream, it might happen that the stream will be null...

Comment: NavigateToString constructs the same MemoryStream and then calls NavigateToStream, so there should not be any difference (but that depends on how you construct your stream). Besides that - what is the benefit of using memory stream in this case? If you want to save some memory - it's better to use temporary FileStream (and even then not sure if it will help a lot).

Comment: I get the difference in behaviour if only the change above happens, so I have to assume that the stream has not been disposed in one case and not the other. The benefit of a MemoryStream is that I am constructing the data in memory, not loading it from a file. I was running into memory limitations when I tried to cast it to a string - works for this demo but not all data sets.

Comment: @Evk if it is calling basically the same code, I guess maybe the process of reading it into a string might include some encoding defaults that are being otherwise missed?

Comment: You can check how it works yourself: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/WebBrowser.cs